# How to use utils.js shared module in Bit components?

Tags: bit.dev

We are trying to build a shared React component library in Bit and I'm wondering how others have handled util modules that are called from a component but are not visually rendered.  Bit refuses to build, saying that the util module is not a jsx (it shouldn't be a jsx, it's shared utilities for the different components).

In before "that should be a hook" and "creating a non-rendering react component" - it's text / date / etc utility functions.

Thanks for any help!

I tried to include the js file in the component directory, and it refused it because it's a non-rendering, non-.jsx file.

Answer (score 1):

### Identifying the problem

I think that your problem comes from using a react template and not a node.js one.

For example, [here](https://bit.cloud/teambit/toolbox/) you can access the full Bit.cloud "Toolbox", and use as example.

```
https://bit.cloud/teambit/toolbox/
```

### Steps to create a node component in a new environment

```
bit new node my-workspace --env teambit.node/node --default-scope my-org.my-scope
bit create node modules/welcome
```

### Documentation

For further reference you can check this [link](https://bit.dev/docs/node-components/node-modules/) in the docs.